# Array to Grid using a table

Tags: javascript

I have been doing some personal projects for fun and most of them have visual representation of boards (ej: sudoku solvers, chess PGN viewer, etc) and I always end up doing something like this:

```
var wid=10;
var hei=6;
var len=(wid*hei);
var map="005000200000000008000600000006000700000040000000500030400000".split("");

var str="<table id=\"board\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr>";

for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(i&&!(i%wid)){
        str+="</tr><tr>";
    }
    str+="<td>"+((map[i]!=0)?map[i]:"&nbsp;")+"</td>";
}

str+="</tr></tbody></table>";

document.body.innerHTML+=str;
```

with CSS styles like:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#board{margin:15px auto;text-align:center;}
#board,#board td{border:1px solid #000;}
#board td{width:45px;height:47px;font-size:20px;}
```

I want to know if there is a better, more readable way to achieve this?, maybe using `arr.join()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you're right, using `join` would solve part of the problem (a global `replace` using a `RegExp` can also help, for instance converting the zeroes into spaces). I'd also suggest using something else to separate rows, this way you won't need the variables `wid`, `hei` and `len` (besides making your map more readable):

```
var map="0050002000-0000000800-0600000006-0007000000-4000000050-0030400000"
    .split("").join("</td><td>")
    .replace(/<td>-<\/td>/g, "</tr><tr>") // replace "-" columns to rows
    .replace(/0/g, "&nbsp;");

var str="<table id=\"board\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td>" +
    map + "</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/HVbVp/)

An alternative (which for my tastes is even better) is only using a string for each row, starting with an array alredy:

```
var map = ["0050002000",
           "0000000800",
           "0600000006",
           "0007000000",
           "4000000050",
           "0030400000"]
    .join('-') // Necessary for the rest of the code to work
    ...
```

This makes the tabular nature of the data visually evident.

Lastly, if you **can't** (or, for any reason, don't want to) change the format of your initial map (inserting those `-` for row separation), one solution would be using a custom regex to insert them for you:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(.{' + wid + '})','g'); // groups "wid" digits
var map = "005000200000000008000600000006000700000040000000500030400000"
    .replace(regex, '$1-') // inserts a "-" after each group
    .replace(/-$/, "") // removes the last "-"
    ...
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/HVbVp/1/), the result is the same.

*Edit:* seeing your performance tests, I decided to add [another test case](http://jsperf.com/boardgenerating/2) modifying your first sample (the fastest), replacing string concatenation to a list of strings with a single join in the end (the most recommended way of doing this). However, the results surprised me: your first version is still faster...

I guess JS array operations are not really as fast as they could be... (I'd expect engine implementors to provide ultra-fast versions of those) Or maybe the issue is with regex processing? (I could try using a string only `replaceAll`, if only the language had such a function built-in...) Well, I guess your version wins in the performance metric. Now that I know string concat is not as bad as people paint it, I won't be ashamed to use it more often... :P

Comment: your skills are awesome, this answer is perfect. Thank you :D!

Comment: just another thing, I think in the second example you meant `["...","..."]` instead of `["..."+"..."]`

Comment: I feel weird posting 3 messages in a row, but I think they must exist: I did a performance test in case someone is interested http://jsperf.com/boardgenerating

Comment: you're right about the `,` - answer updated. I also added another test case to your [performance test](http://jsperf.com/boardgenerating/2), but the results surprised me! See the edit above.

Answer (score 5):

Despite already having accepted an answer, I'd like to point out a different way to approach this.

Since you are building the board with JavaScript I'm assuming that you want to modify the content of the board dynamically. (If not then the question would be why you are using JavaScript and not a server-side generation).

In that case it could make sense to separate generation and filling the board. That way you could simply exchange each method without affecting the other.

For generation you could continue to use your solution just with empty or default values, or use DOM generation:

```
var rowCount = 6;
var colCount = 10;
var board = document.createElement('table');
for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {
  var row = board.insertRow();
  for (var c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
    row.insertCell();
  }
}
```

Or simply use static HTML.

And then you write a function that sets the value of a cell which will work no matter how you created the board. Something like:

```
function setBoardValue(board, x, y, value) {
   board.rows(y).cells(x).innerHTML = value;
}
```

And then you can loop over your "map" in anyway you like and call it:

```
var map="005000200000000008000600000006000700000040000000500030400000".split("");

for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
  setBoardValue(board, i % colCount, Math.floor(i / rowCount), map[i] != 0 ? map[i] : "&nbsp;");
}
```

In the end this solution if technically slower that your solution, but usually not in an amount that would be noticeable by the user and you have an advantage with the separation of the concerns.